# Is there a way to reject messages that contain particular words in channels?

Tags: microsoft-teams

My company has a policy of only sending passwords via encrypted email. However, that takes a little more effort then just asking and sending a quick message during a thread. Is there a way for Teams to reject a message containing a word, in this case password, and give a rejection message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a programming related question, so this isn't the place to ask it. I'll answer it anyway though.

We call this "Data Loss Prevention" (DLP) and it's available in some versions of Office 365. We have not yet added it for Teams but it's definitely on the roadmap. Please use "share an idea" via the Feedback (lightbulb) icon at the lower left of Teams and add your vote.